# node.js / express / mysql / serialport / socket.io

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, serial-port, socket.io

i'm working on this project using all the modules mentioned in the title of this question.
When I send a text message, the computer can read it through serialport, and the first thing it will do is see if the number is registered in the database. This is the code for that:

```
function consultarNumero(head, body, numero){
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM devices WHERE nro_telefono = "'+numero+'"', function(err, result){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }else{
      if(result[0]['id']!=null){
        var idEmbarcacion = result[0]['id'];
        //readingData.dividirPartes(head, body, idEmbarcacion); <- some other function
      }else{
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

This code works, because the phone number I'm using for the tests IS registered in the database, however if i send a message from another cellphone, an error will come up saying "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined".

So obviously "if(result[0]['id']!=null)" isn't the right way to go.
I've tried "if(result.length)!=0" but the length of the resulting array will always be greater than 0, even if the number isn't registered, because if it can't find anything it will return 'undefined'.

Of course, I know if the hpone number isn't registered, then 'id' will be unexistant. The thing is I can't figure out how to edit this query to add a different behaviour if the number isn't registered,because when the system is implemented, it is possible to receive messages from random phone numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `result` is indeed `undefined` when there are no results, then `result[0]` would also be `undefined`. The following example shouldn't pass the first evaluation of `if (result)` and then it should reach the else safely.

```
if (result && result[0] && result[0]['id']) {}
```

Comment: great, that worked! I didn't think getting into the array little by little while evaluating would be the solution. Thanks